# How understand the logic underneath standardization methods?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, standardization

I have a dataset of very different data and I want to make a multivariate analysis. I am a biology student so I'm very poor in statistics and so I am willing to study this fascinating yet important topic!

My problem is this: I have to put together in a db-RDA (distance-based ReDundancy Analysis) elemental concentrations, salinity, pHs, redox potentials, various other concentrations (even ecotoxicological ones), and species abundances from 16S sequencing.

The tutorial I'm following ([link to Applied Multivariate statistics in R](https://uw.pressbooks.pub/appliedmultivariatestatistics/)) doesn't explain what kind of standardization I have to make yet making a 'range' one for putting together (as explanatory variables) latitude, longitude, and altitude. I don't have this very kind of data so I need to understand the reason behind the different kinds of standardization.

Where should I learn about it? The tutorial uses the vegan function `decostand()` in R.